# How do I find duplicated id's in a list of ID's

Tags: xml, vb.net

From the xml below which in my vb code is in objXmlNode2, I would like to check for CaseEventInternalID that is a duplicate. How do I do that? I should be able to find one.

The CaseEventInternalIDs are in a list strCaseEventInternalIDList. I need to check for duplicates in that list.

```
strCaseEventInternalIDList(i) = objXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("CaseEventInternalID").InnerText
                    i = i + 1
```

**XML doc which is in  Dim objXmlNode2 As XmlNode**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
    <Result>
        <CaseEventInternalID>1810457949</CaseEventInternalID>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <CaseEventInternalID>1810457949</CaseEventInternalID>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

**My vb code not working**

```
For Each objXmlNode2 In objXmlResponseDoc2.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Result")
                        If (objXmlNode2.SelectSingleNode("CaseEventInternalID").InnerText > 1) Then
                            Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.InternalResource.Database.ExecuteScalar("DELETE FROM DocumentPublishingLookup WHERE CaseEventInternalID = " + objXmlNode2.SelectSingleNode("CaseEventInternalID").InnerText, strDPDatabase, strDPServer, strDPUser, strDPPW)
                            'remove from node list
                            objXmlNode2.ParentNode.RemoveChild(objXmlNode2)
                        End If
                    Next
```

Comment: Maybe SelectSingleNode will always select only a single node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy to use Linq to XML then this is the easy way:

```
Dim xd = XDocument.Parse(xml)

Dim duplicateIds = _
    xd _
        .Root _
        .Elements("Result") _
        .Elements("CaseEventInternalID") _
        .Select(Function (x) x.Value) _
        .GroupBy(Function (x) x) _
        .Where(Function (x) x.Skip(1).Any()) _
        .SelectMany(Function (x) x.Take(1)) _
        .ToArray()
```

That returns:

```
{ 1810457949 }
```